# Insert rows from two arrays into mysql table in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to insert values into table from two arrays. I need to insert corresponding values from **array1** and **array2** into table as a row. ie, The table row looks like:

```
value1, array1[0], array2[0] ...
value1, array1[1], array2[1] ...
```

I tried doing it with two foreach loop. But the value inside the innerloop is repeating.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
$serviceamt=$_POST['amount'];
foreach($servicetype as $sertype)
{
foreach($serviceamt as $seramt)
{
$amcinsert2=mysql_query("insert into amc_service_types (amc_service_id,service_type,service_amount) values('$id','$sertype','$seramt')");
break;
}

}
?>
```

When I execute this, the table will look like:

```
value1, array1[0], array2[0] ...
value2, array1[1], array2[0] ...
value3, array1[2], array2[0] ...
```

I didn't understand where should I change my code. Can anyone help me..

Comment: use `for` loop instead

Comment: if you want to repeat `VALUE1` everytime, you must insert it statically, but why array2 is giving wrong result i dont know....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your arrays are both numerically indexed and have the same keys, you can loop over them like this:

```
for( $i = 0 ; $i < count( $servicetype ) ; $i++ ) {
  $amcinsert2=mysql_query("insert into amc_service_types (amc_service_id,service_type,service_amount) values('$id','" . $servicetype[$i] "','" . $serviceamt[$i] . "')");

}
```

Also, mysql_* functions are deprecated, you should replace them with either PDO or mysqli_* functions.

Answer (score 1):

at the begining you have to make sure you have the same size of both arrays, actually what you are doing will add n*n combinations to the mysql , and not what you wanna do ,the break will escape the for loop from the first run which is anyway is gonna be the first array[0], so try to do like this :

```
<?php
$servicetype=$_POST['servicetype'];
$serviceamt=$_POST['amount'];
var i=0;
foreach($servicetype as $sertype)
{
$amcinsert2=mysql_query("insert into amc_service_types (amc_service_id,service_type,service_amount) values('$id','$sertype','$serviceamt[$i]')");
$i++;  
}
?>
```